# Join query with multiple ON condition not working in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) 
     LEFT JOIN `users_phone_numbers`     
              ON `users`.`id`= `users_phone_numbers`.`user_id` 
     LEFT JOIN `phone_number`
             ON (`phone_number`.`id`= `users_phone_numbers`.`phone_num_id` AND users_phone_numbers.is_active = 1)
WHERE `users`.`id` = 56
```

i have code like this in codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('users_phone_numbers',
                              'users.id= users_phone_numbers.user_id',
                              'left');
            $this->db->join('phone_number',
                              '(phone_number.id= users_phone_numbers.phone_num_id AND users_phone_numbers.is_active = 1)',
                              'left'); 
$this->db->where('users.id = '. $id); 
 $result =  $q->result_array();
```

But i got this error

[image: But i got this error]

Comment: When you do a phone_number join, do you really have an opening bracket  in conditions list? Because on your image that part looks like `...JOIN \`phone_number\` ON \`phone_number\`.\`id\`...` instead of `...JOIN \`phone_number\` ON (\`phone_number\`.\`id\`...`

Comment: I have "(" in on condition . I checked this "(" 5 times in code

Comment: Why don't you try by just removing `braces` from your condition.

Comment: Then query will execute but the result is wrong

Comment: why codeigniter remove "(" on condition?

Comment: Looks like that is a bug in codeigniter. Similar issue here with workaround proposed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913343/codeigniter-how-to-have-brackets-in-a-join-condition. Also, I would try to put space before opening bracket like here `join('phone_number',
                              ' (phone_number.id.`

Answer (score 3):

If you check Codeigniter's handling of the condition function, you will see the following:

```
// Strip apart the condition and protect the identifiers
if (preg_match('/([\w\.]+)([\W\s]+)(.+)/', $cond, $match))
```

Codeigniter is stripping the opening bracket from the query. Can you not move the LEFT JOIN additional clause within the WHERE clause to get around this?

EDIT:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('users_phone_numbers',
                              'users.id= users_phone_numbers.user_id',
                              'left');
            $this->db->join('phone_number',
                              'phone_number.id= users_phone_numbers.phone_num_id)',
                              'left'); 
$this->db->where(array('users.id => '. $id, 'users_phone_numbers.is_active' => 1)); 
 $result =  $q->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the second condition of the `join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->db->join('phone_number',
                              'phone_number.id= users_phone_numbers.phone_num_id AND users_phone_numbers.is_active = 1',
                              'left');
```

remove brackets like above. it works for me when there is no bracket